# Conversion formula from RGB to YCbCr

Tags: image, image-processing, colors, rgb

Whats the real conversion formula for this because I found so many ways on how to convert I don't know which one is real

From wikipedia:
[image]

From microsoft https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff635643.aspx [image]:

and microsoft is the same with this conversion site http://www.equasys.de/colorconversion.html:

[image]

Can anybody explain the difference of the formula?

Comment: The first one is for converting *analog* to digital, allowing "footrom" and "headroom" (explained on Wikipedia). The latter ones are the JPEG conversion, allowing usage of the full 8 bit range (0...255), also explained in the Wikipedia article, a little further down. So... It depends on what your input is.

Comment: I dont understand the explanation on wikipedia about the first one, so If my input is JPEG I will use the second conversion to get the YCbCr?

Comment: If your input is JPEG, then the data is most likely already in YCbCr (the JPEG variant). So I'm not sure what you want to achieve by that... But if your input is digital data, then using the second version makes the most sense, yes, as you should be able to convert back and forth lossless.

Comment: Check out IPP documentation: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/503873

Comment: Here is a wayback machine link to the second link in the question which seems to no longer be valid: https://web.archive.org/web/20180421030430/http://www.equasys.de/colorconversion.html

Comment: @HaraldK This is a generic question about an image colour space conversion formula. So is the suggested duplicate question, but it concerns a specific language and framework. So, this is not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 4):

If it still actual they are almost the same. Differences are what value ranges you'll get in the result.

From Wiki's matrix (R',G',B' = 0..1) values will be: **Y** = 0..219, **Cb** = -112..112, **Cr** = -112..112. You can bring it to other matrices with dividing Y formula by 219, and Cb, Cr fomulas by 224.

From Microsoft's one (R,G,B = 0..255) you'll get **Y** = 0..255, **Cb** ≈ -127.5 .. 127.5, **Cr** ≈ -127.5 .. 127.5

The third matrix solves problems with negative numbers by adding 128 to them. The difference from Microsoft's matrix lies in the matrices multiplication.

Comment: Where are the numbers in the matrices coming from? They seem rather arbitrary.

Comment: @SasQ Well, I believe they are based on color models of human vision.